# OpenCV and haartraining - how to reduce time for calculation?

Tags: multithreading, opencv, haar-classifier

Is it possible to improve the performance of haartraining application. If I see well it uses only one thread. Does nature of his algorithm exclude using multithreading?I'm looking for possibility for increasing speed of calculating classificator therefore my question is: *only one way to decrease calculation time is to use faster procesor - number of cores doesn't have matter*?

Comment: Did you try to enable OpenMP support for utilizing multi-threading and shared memory? haartraining application supports OpenMP (for example `cvhaartraining.cpp` file contains the directives `#pragma omp`).

Comment: I use haarttraining after compilation. I'm sorry, I forgot to add I am pythons developer

Comment: As I know the haartraining application is available only in C++. You can recompile this one and use wrapper on Python.